# How to set class member in C++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm using JNI to get a variable from java and set it to a class member to my C++ class.

Here's my code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_class_classname_Event(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jFloatarray arr)
{
    jfloat *_arr = env->GetFloatArrayElements(arr, 0);
    env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(arr, _arr, 0);

}
```

How can I set the value of a C++ class member to arr?
I'm pretty new to C++ and JNI, so bear with me...

Thank you.

Comment: Is the question about copying alle the element to a C++ array ?  Or just one specific element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of the direction of the copy, so here two answers:

**1) Copy the java array to a C++ class member:**

JNI manages the array returned by GetFloatArrayElements(), so you can't keep it after its release.  If you want to keep in in C++ you could clone however it :

```
jsize l = env->GetArrayLength(arr); 
jfloat *_arr = env->GetFloatArrayElements(arr, 0);
mycpp_arr = new jfloat[l]; 
copy(_arr, _arr+l, mycpp_arr);  
env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(arr, _arr, 0);
```

By the way, I'd suggest to go for a vector instead of an array.

**2) Or copy the changes made in C++ back to Java:**

It all depends. If you want to do int within the JNI callback:

```
jboolean isCopy; 
jfloat *_arr = env->GetFloatArrayElements(arr, &isCopy);

// if isCopy==JNI_FALSE you work directelyon the original Java data
// if it's JNI_TRUE, you work on a temporary copy

... // do your stuff, supposing that you want all changes to _arr[] reflected
    // in the original Java array

env->ReleaseFloatArrayElements(arr, _arr, JNI_COMMIT); // copy back 
// nota: if isCopy was JNI_TRUE you could opt for JNI_ABORT to cancel changes
// but this is ignored if you did your chang eon the original daa
```

Comment: Neither answer answers the question asked.